# Error with conda update: OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

As the title says every time I try to run the command `conda update --all`  I get immediately the error that you can see at the end of this post.

This only happens with a particular environment. If I launch the command from conda base environment or any other conda environment the package updates are first downloaded and installed but the same error reappears at the end of the installation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1132, in __call__
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 69, in main_subshell
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 122, in do_call
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 121, in wrapper
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 20, in execute
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 264, in install
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 134, in solve_for_transaction
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 177, in solve_for_diff
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 248, in solve_final_state
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1110, in __init__
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/core/prefix_data.py", line 133, in iter_records
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/core/prefix_data.py", line 162, in _prefix_records
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 84, in decorated
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/core/prefix_data.py", line 66, in load
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: b'/home/jesus/anaconda3/envs/jesus-ml-1/conda-meta'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 112, in main
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1432, in conda_exception_handler
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1135, in __call__
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1175, in handle_exception
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1186, in handle_unexpected_exception
  File "/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1248, in print_unexpected_error_report
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/home/jesus/anaconda3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py'
```

I already clone the environment that thrown the error immediately. In the clone of the environment the update is performed but in the end the error always appears.

Comment: Are you on a mac? You could try to increase your file limit: `ulimit -n 4096`

Comment: I've ubuntu. I still tried the command but the error remains